# Meteorjs Mongodb how to query a date with momentjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, momentjs

In Meteor, I create a winner document this way:

```
var winner = {
                participant_id: array[randomIndex]["_id"], //don't worry about the array[randomIndex]
                creation_date: new Date()
            };
id = Winners.insert(winner);
```

Later, I want to know how many winners I have today. I tried it many ways, but I couldn't succeed to get the right result.

The last thing I tried is this one:

```
Winners.find({creation_date: {"$gte": moment().startOf('day'), "$lt": moment().add('days',1)}}).count();
```

But the result is always equal to zero.

I guess the reason is that moment().startOf('day') is not a date object but I've no clue how to query it the right way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to convert the moment object back to a `Date` so meteor/mongo can process the query. You can do that by appending a call to [toDate](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) like so:

```js
var startDate = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
var endDate = moment().add('days',1).toDate();
Winners.find({creation_date: {$gte: startDate, $lt: endDate}}).count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:
creation_date:new Date().getTime()
```

and

```
// you can still use moment:
moment().startOf('day').valueOf()

// query:
Winners.find({
   creation_date: {
     "$gte": moment().startOf('day').valueOf(),
     "$lt":  moment().add('days',1).valueOf()
   }
}).count();
```